# debhelper for dh_installinit, override the exit on failed service start

Tags: package-management, deb

I have the following in rules file:

```sh
override_dh_installinit:
      dh_installinit --restart-after-upgrade
```

The auto generated posint script has:

```sh
if [ -n "$2" ]; then
    _dh_action=restart
else
    _dh_action=start
fi
invoke-rc.d mySerivce $_dh_action || exit $?
```

What I am trying to do is to remove the 'exit $?' from the last line above, to be:

```sh
invoke-rc.d mySerivce $_dh_action
```

I tried this in the rules file:

```sh
override_dh_installinit:
    dh_installinit --no-start --restart-after-upgrade
    if [ -n "$2" ]; then
        _dh_action=restart
    else
        _dh_action=start
    fi
    invoke-rc.d mySerivce $_dh_action
```

But got error when build the package:
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: end of file unexpected

This error was on the line that has 'if [ -n "$2" ]; then'

I looked into the option that debhelp has, but didn't find any option that can take of the 'exit $?' above.

I am kind out of options at this stage.